# Garage door has been lifting slowly off the ground over time

Tags: garage-door

The other day our garage door wouldn’t shut. It would go down and bounce back up. We adjusted the travel, and it was back to normal working condition. Or so I thought. It starts closed all the way. Then I go out the next day and see it has raised off the ground a small amount. Opening and closing doesn’t fix it, it keeps it opened that small amount. It’s like it’s losing travel distance at night or something.

What could be going on?

Edit

I have a LiftMaster 8500 Pre 2022

Comment: Disconnect it from the chain over night, to find out if it is motor or the springs

Comment: Garage door spring adjustment is needed if the door becomes too easy to open (your case) or slams shut. It is actually a dangerous work, if you do not have the right tools, and do not know how. For DIY, there are plenty of instructions online.

Comment: It could also be the floor.

Comment: @Ruskes I pulled the cord to disconnect the door from the opener (while in the 1” off the ground) and it closed. So I don’t think it’s the springs.

Answer (score 3):

Had a guy come out and diagnose. The issue was with the travel sensor. The replacement part was $30 and we haven't had any issues since.